# I know components of a vector and it's tail. How do I work out its head?

Tags: vectors

Vector AB has component 3,-1 and it's tail is -2,4, find its head. Help me out

Comment: The tail + the vector = the head.

Comment: The problem I mentioned above... can help me with it? I keep getting 5,-5 as the tail while correct answer is 1,3 ??

Comment: Is the question correct?

Comment: I'm new on stack exchange, does  it allow to attach photos?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Maybe it is the tail $A$ that is at $(-2, 4)$?

Comment: OK sorry the exact question is : calculate head of vector AB knowing that its component is 3,-1 and it's -2,4

Comment: Can you just explain how head +vector gives us the tail?

Comment: If you write "tail" when you mean "head" and "head" when you mean "tail" then you will end up with some very confusing comments and answers, especially after you "fix" the wording of the question.

Comment: Oops lesson learnt David 

Comment: First, an actual **vector** doesn't have a "head" or "tail"- a specific representation of a vector does.  The vector with components <x, y> can be represented by taking any point, say, (a, b) as "tail" and then (a+ x, y+ b) as "head".  That follows from the [b]definition[/b] of "components of a vector"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$(x,y)+(3,-1)=(-2,4)$ gives:
$$
x+3=-2 \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad y-1=4
$$

Comment: I did the same Emilio, but the correct answer seems to be 1,3 (printed so). The 1,3 answer is incorrect ?

Comment: This is the correct answer to the given question.

Comment: Sorry Emilio actually it's the tail which is -2,4 and head to be found out.

Comment: How did you get the equation is it a formula or something?

Comment: Thank you Emilia ,Peter explained it pretty well thanks for your quick response 

Answer (score 1):

You can get the solution geometrically by starting at the first point and using the offset.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the tail $A$ is just a vector from origin to $A$:

$$\vec{OA} = (-2, 4)$$

By vector addition,

$$\vec{OB} = \vec{OA} + \vec {AB}$$

And $\vec{OB}$ is also just the coordinates of the head $B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter for quick repky I'm good now